# Pyspark windows function not applying to entire dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I'm encountering an issue when it comes to applying a lag/windows function to entire dataframe on a condition.

I want to times the previous rows value(value1), with the current rows value(value2), from week 2 onwards.

Here is my data:

'''

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

data = [
    (1, 1, 1),
    (2, 0, 5),
    (3, 0, 10),
    (4, 0, 20),
    (5, 0, 30),
    (6, 0, 40)
]
columns = ["week", "value1", "value2"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
```

'''

Here is my logic to do the calc:

'''

```
w=Window.orderBy("week")
                          
df2 = df.withColumn('value1',
                    f.when((f.col('week') > 1),
                           f.lag(df['value1']).over(w) * df['value2'] 
                          ).otherwise(
                        f.col('value1')
                    )
                   )
```

'''

My output looks like this:

[image]

You can see only week 2 is following the logic.

Week 3 should be 50 (5 * 10), not zero...

Can anyone please help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this solution:

```
w=Window.orderBy("week")
df = (
    df
    .withColumn('value1', f.when(f.col('week') > 1, f.product(f.col('value2').cast(DoubleType())).over(w)).otherwise(f.col('value1')))
)
df.show()
```

And the output:

```
+----+---------+------+                                                         
|week|   value1|value2|
+----+---------+------+
|   1|      1.0|     1|
|   2|      5.0|     5|
|   3|     50.0|    10|
|   4|   1000.0|    20|
|   5|  30000.0|    30|
|   6|1200000.0|    40|
+----+---------+------+
```

I hope I understood what you were looking for in the comments correctly. Check out this solution:

```
w=Window.orderBy("week").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, -1)
df = (
    df
    .withColumn('value2_array', f.collect_list(f.col('value2')).over(w))
    .withColumn('value1', f.when(f.col('week') > 1, f.expr('aggregate(value2_array, value2, (val, x) -> val - x)')).otherwise(f.col('value1')))
)
df.show()
```

And the output is:

```
+----+------+------+------------------+                                         
|week|value1|value2|      value2_array|
+----+------+------+------------------+
|   1|     1|     1|                []|
|   2|     4|     5|               [1]|
|   3|     4|    10|            [1, 5]|
|   4|     4|    20|        [1, 5, 10]|
|   5|    -6|    30|    [1, 5, 10, 20]|
|   6|   -26|    40|[1, 5, 10, 20, 30]|
+----+------+------+------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, turns out the issue was the version of pyspark I was using. @ARCrow, how would I change this to minus instead of times?

Comment: @Beans_in_my_shoes I've updated the answer. Please check it out.

Comment: sorry could you help me again with this? I want when week >1, for value1 to = previous row value1 - current row value2. so week 3 should be 6, week 4 should be 14, etc...